# INSERT auto increment primary keys into another table inside transaction

Tags: sql, postgresql, primary-key, junction-table

I have 3 tables `recipe`, `ingredient`, and the junction table for the previous two `recipes_ingredients`

recipe: `recipe_id | name | process`

ingredient: `ingredient_id | name| type`

recipes_ingredients: `id | recipe_id | ingredient_id`

When I INSERT a record in `recipe` I want to insert also records for the ingredients of this recipe in `ingredient`. To relate the two tables I have to insert a record in `recipes_ingredients` for every ingredient.
I thought to use a transaction an do something like this:

```
BEGIN;  -- start transaction

INSERT INTO recipe (recipe_id, name, process) VALUES ();
INSERT INTO ingredient (ingredient_id, name, type) VALUES ();
INSERT INTO recipes_ingredients (recipe_id, ingredient_id) VALUES ();

COMMIT; -- end transaction
```

The problem is that every primary key is SERIAL data type, so is automatically inserted with auto increment.
So how can I insert `recipe_id` and `ingredient_id` in `recipes_ingredients` if I don't know them?

Comment: You will have to use the scope_Identity function equivalent in postgresql. read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=SCOPE_IDENTITY%20%28%29%20returns%20the%20value%20from%20the%20insert,inserted%20identity%20value.%20Here%20is%20the%20result%20set.

Comment: `INSERT INTO recipe ... RETURNING id`